# How to refer to one occasion of an interviewee talking?

Tags: single-word-requests

For my thesis, I want to refer to interviewees talking for one occasion. The interview was not one-on-one, but conducted in a focus group. A focus group is a group interview without requiring consensus, where the group typically consists of 6 to 10 interviewees.

An example makes it much clearer, so here's a fictional transcript of a focus group:

```
A: Hello, what are your names?
B: My name is B.
C: My name is C.
D: And my name is D.
A: Next question, what is your opinion about SE?
B: Well, that asks for a long answer. I'm mostly positive. Some things can be better though.
```

My goal is to refer to one sentence here, like the last long one by `B`, both directly like `on occasion X, B said that ...`, but also abstractly like `B talked on 45 of 399 occasions`, where occasion[s] is replaced with the word I'm looking for.

It can't be called one *sentence* as such, because it consists of multiple sentences. Calling it a *citation* also doesn't cover it completely, neither does *case* or *event*. *Occasion* comes closest, but results in extra explanation, because occasion can mean a lot of things.

Does anybody know the academic term used for this?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.   I don't understand.  If it's an interview, and you're not referring to *sentences*, wouldn't the interviewee always talk on exactly half of the "occasions"?  If we stipulate that the interviewer got the last word, wouldn't B always have talked on 199 of 399 occasions?  And, if so, what information are you really trying to communicate?

Comment: I didn't want to give unnecessary details, so I left out that the interviews were focus groups. A focus group is a group interview without needing consensus. So there are a few people talking (normally 6-10). Apart from having more people involved, focus groups are the same as interviews. They are of course used in different situations with different reasoning.

Comment: When you're asking for a word, information on how it will be used ***is*** a ***necessary*** part of the question.   I advise you to [edit] your question with the information from the above comment.

Comment: Perhaps "topic(s)" (*a subject of conversation or discussion*)

Comment: One reason for some of the misunderstanding in your original Q. may be that you used the *singular* possessive form "interviewee's" in 2 places, instead of the plural form "interviewees". I've corrected this - and I hope that is what you intend.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you mean (1) B spoke a total of 399 times, and on 45 of that occasions he mentioned XYZ; or (2) The number of times that *anyone* spoke was 399 in total; and 45 of those times were B speaking & 354 times were other people speaking.

Comment: @TrevorD: My main goal is the second one, but in the end that depends on the context. Its possible that further on in my text I'll be using the first one, as I can think of several options of why and when one wants to use the first one. On your other comment: you're probably right, my English grammer isn't the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the "occasions" are specifically referring to times when a question was asked and answered, I would think that you can replace **occasion** with either

"**question**" ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/question))

> an act or instance of asking

or

"**inquiry**" ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquiry))

> a request for information

- the interviewee is prompted to speak by your questions. When you refer to the talking performed by the interviewee, it is in the form of a

**response** ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/response))

> an answer or reply, as in words or in some action.

Therefore, the resultant sentence would read

> B ***responded*** to 45 of 399 ***inquiries/questions***

Answer (score 6):

Although you could consider “contributions,” for participants are arguably contributing/making contributions to the focus group each time/occasion they say something, I would reserve “contribution” to refer to, describe, and evaluate their total, overall contribution (or lack thereof) to the group, and refer to each individual occasion as an [“utterance”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utterance); …[“statement”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statement) ; … or [“remark”](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/remark_1), with "**remark**" being, in my non-academic opinion, the most idiomatic of the three to use in the blanks in your examples:

"in remark X, B said that ..."
"B **made** 45 of [the] 399 remarks."

Definition of *utterance* (from *Merriam-Webster*)
1 :  something uttered; especially :  an oral or written statement :  a stated or published expression

Definition of *statement* (from *Merriam-Webster*)
 1 :  something stated: as
a:  a single declaration or remark :  assertion

Definition of **remark** [countable noun] (from *Oxford Learner’s Dictionary)
something that you say or write which expresses an opinion, a thought, etc. about somebody/something

Comment: I prefer "remark".

Answer (score 2):

I think "comment" would work perfectly here.

> Comment
>   noun
>   1. a remark, observation, or criticism

Comment: "comment" is the commonly used phrase in my experience. Add a reference/definition and I'll +1.

Comment: @Waylan There you go